# Workaround for grouped layers to stay collapsed when opening project

Tags: qgis, windows, qgis-2.6, table-of-contents, group-layer

Using QGIS 2.6.1 on Windows 7, whenever I open a project containing layers in various groups, they appear expanded. This is regardless if the project is saved when the layers are collapsed. I'm guessing this is a little bug but is there a workaround?

I am open to python, not open to a newer version of QGIS although it would be useful to know if this is solved.

Comment: Strange, when I use QGIS 2.6.0 the project remembers if a group is expanded or collapsed. This setting is written to the project file (QGS) like <layer-tree-layer expanded="0".. or <layer-tree-layer expanded="1"...Do you have these tag in your project QGS file?

Comment: @Jakob - Many thanks, apparently my QGIS does not save the `expanded=0` tags correctly (not sure why that is) but I manually changed them and works great. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept =)

Comment: This bug still exists in 3.16. Some layer groups are expanded even if you collapse them and save. They will even be expanded if you edit the .qgs file and change the `1`s to `0`s (see Jakob answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use QGIS 2.6.0 the project remembers if a group is expanded or collapsed. This setting is written to the project file (QGS) like `<layer-tree-layer expanded="0">` or `<layer-tree-layer expanded="1">` Do you have these tags in your project QGS file?